# Getting class param in non-extended form

Tags: java, class, function, extends

I have a function, say:

```
 public void doWhatever(ExtendedClass class) {}
```

Which the class param is a class, say:

```
 public class SomeClass extends ExtendedClass {}
```

How can I get the "SomeClass" name in the function where I ask for "ExtendedClass"?

Comment: Realized I had a grammar mistake in my title as well; glad it was removed to seize embarrassment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if it is an instance of `SomeClass` with the `instanceof` operator:

```
public void doWhatever(ExtendedClass cls) {
    if (cls instanceof SomeClass) {
        //do stuff
        SomeClass sCls = (SomeClass)cls; // you can cast it to SomeClass
                                         // once you know that it is one
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not the most _universal_ solution, but it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you'd want to do this, but:

```
String className = class.getClass().getSimpleName();
```